# Display list when click into field in Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I've got this field

```
           <div>
                <input type = "text"  class = "form-control" id = "driverplus" placeholder = "Fahrer">
            </div>
```

and i use jquery-autocomplete from https://www.devbridge.com/.

How can i trigger autocomplete when i just click into the "driverplus" field without typing anything to display the whole list of entries via ajax.

```
$('#driverplus').devbridgeAutocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    serviceUrl: '/driverplusautocomplete',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
           alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + " for id " + 

    }
})
```

the option minLength: 0 does not work, also deferRequestBy: 0 has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

since there are a few obstacles with devbridge autocomplete i changed my framework to http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/. works excellent!
just in case someone needs it, here is the solution:

```
  let flexdatalist = $('#driverplus').flexdatalist({
    minLength: 0,
    searchIn: 'name',
    selectionRequired: true,
    valueProperty: '*',
    searchContain:true,
    data: '/driverplusautocomplete'
});
```

php laravel code in controller

```
   public function driverplusautocomplete() {

    $models = User::where('driver',1)
        ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $arrtmp = array();
    foreach ($models as $key => $val) {
        array_push($arrtmp, $val);
    }
    return $arrtmp;
}
```